# Highstock Reset Zoom button not resetting zoom as desired

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart and I manually check in the `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes` function to ensure the start time is adequately after the end time. If it isn't it shows an error and uses the `xAxis[0].setExtremes` method to go back to the last valid min and max values for the chart which were stored previously.

This all works fine, however if I then click on the "Reset Zoom" button it tries to set the time to an invalid value, so the error prompts again and the zoom is set to the last working values (which are the current ones).

So my question is, where does the Reset Zoom button get it's values to reset to from? And can I change them? Or more generally just how does the "Reset zoom" button work?

Comment: Reset zoom just calls `chart.zoomOut()`. Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: I didn't realise Reset zoom doesn't effect the y axis when using an xy zooming style. It seems it zooms out to the width of the navigator selection (which took me a good while to realise), I was for some reason expecting it to zoom out to the last used value.

Comment: This may explain a little: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/979

Comment: I had already stumbled upon that and it was very helpful, thanks!